# Swagger openapi spec 3.0 resulting None is not of type object

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am trying to use openapi spec 3.0.
My login end point is specified as

```
/login:
    post:
      description: User Login.
      operationId: swagger_server.controllers.default_controller.login_post

      requestBody:
        required: false
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Login"
        description: Login object 

      parameters:
        - name: Authorization
          in: header
          description: an authorization header
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: x-api-key
          in: header
          description: an authorization header
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Successfully logged in.
```

I am trying to define an endpoint where the requestbody is optional (I read that it is the default behavior). I seem to get an error `None is not of type object`. Is this expected behavior? What am I doing wrong? Appreciate your input.

Comment: Your endpoint is ok. Your error must be in the component section in login scheme. Could you show the code for this section?

Comment: This is how the component section for login looks like

``` 

Login:

      type: object

      properties:

        UN:
          type: string
        PW:
          type: string
```

Comment: Apologies. Not sure how to format this...

Comment: What server-side framework do you use? Flask+Connexion? How do you send the request to your API (e.g. from Swagger UI, Postman, from a client app, etc.)? Also please post the request data (headers+body) that results in that error.

Comment: Server side is Flask+Connexion. I am using Curl to test this. `curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" <server>/login' This seem to give error but  `curl -k -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{}" <server>/login' seem to work fine.

Comment: Any takers on this please?

Comment: Any takers please?